# Android dip vis pixels. Having terrible trouble with my 2d tilemap?

Tags: java, android, 2d, tiles

I've searched/read all of the dip to pixel translations, but I'm feeling a little overwhelmed by it all, I'm sure it's incredibly easy to grasp, but I'm quite old school :( So I'm pleading for some help on the matter, if anyone's got the time.

I've got an android game using a SurfaceView, which draws a 2d tilemap to the screen for a puzzle game. I've stupidly hardcoded all values for my device, just to get it up and running. Now it's pretty much 100% complete, I went out and bought a Samsung Galaxy tab, and it looks like poop! Can anyone shed some light on how to get the following code to work in dip/dp, rather than pixels please?

TIA!

```
    public static int MAX_WIDTH                 = 320; // width of map area
    public static int MAX_HEIGHT                = 480; // height of map area
    public static final int TILE_SIZE_2     = 32; // tile size dimensions
```

I then set my map area to a pre-defined area

```
    map_area = new int[MAX_WIDTH/TILE_SIZE][MAX_HEIGHT/TILE_SIZE];
```

Here is how I setup the levels themselves (you'll see what I mean when I'm old school) - It's a shambles, I know! I do have time to waste though!

```
        public void mapStringToMap(String mapString){
    // clear the map first
    int i= 0;
    rocks = new CTile[mapString.length()];

    try
    {
    // now add the rock types to the map array
    for(int x = 0; x<MAX_WIDTH/TILE_SIZE; x++){
        for(int y =0; y<MAX_HEIGHT/TILE_SIZE; y++){
            rocks[i] = new CTile();
            setMapData(x, y, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mapString.charAt(i))));
            rocks[i].setRockType(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mapString.charAt(i))));
            rocks[i].setX(x*TILE_SIZE);
            rocks[i].setY(y*TILE_SIZE);
            rocks[i].setRockId(i);

            if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mapString.charAt(i))) == GOLD_TILE){
                rocks[i].setRockBitmap(goldTile);
                // increase the number of rocks for this level
                level_rock_count+=3;
            }else if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mapString.charAt(i))) == SILVER_TILE){
                rocks[i].setRockBitmap(silverTile);
                // increase the number of rocks for this level
                level_rock_count+=2;
            }else if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mapString.charAt(i))) == COPPER_TILE){
                rocks[i].setRockBitmap(copperTile);
                // increase the number of rocks for this level
                level_rock_count++;
            }else if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mapString.charAt(i))) == START_TILE){
                dave.setX(x*TILE_SIZE);
                dave.setY(y*TILE_SIZE);
            }else if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mapString.charAt(i))) == DIAMOND_TILE_1){
                rocks[i].setRockBitmap(diamondTile1);
                // increase the number of rocks for this level by 4!
                level_rock_count += 4;
            }

            // move on 
            i++;
        }
    }
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As a result, it works wonderfully on my device, but I'm trying to cover as many handsets as I can, obviously. The drawing of the maps is pretty much identical to above, the whole grid values x/y * TILE_SIZE etc.

I'm sure I'm going to kick myself, but I just can't wrap my head around anything I've read.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

px = dp * (dpi / 160)
px = pixel value, dp = display independent pixels, dpi = dots per inch (your device's resolution)

This is a simple fromula for the conversion.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
float xDpi = dm.xdpi;
float yDpi = dm.ydpi;
```

These are the x and y dpi values, so according to them, you can redefine your pixel hardcoded values to dip values (which will be different for horizontal and vertical axes)

Comment: Would this override the default size of my map area?, as that would have to stay constant. I'm guessing that I can use a reverse formula to properly display my 320x480 map as is, but with specific dp's to draw correctly on larger screens. I'd tried the "setFixedSize" at SurfaceHolder level, but I'd rather not use that. 

That's helped a lot, many thanks!

Comment: It would scale your map accordingly, if you want it to remain constant, you can let it be defined in pixels. Glad to help :)

Comment: This was the case, however I've got further issues because I'm using a fixed string as my level data, which expects 320x480 / 32 tiles, so we're talking 10 cells across and 15 down.

        000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000003001000300000000000000000000000000000000000301001000000000000000000000000003000030300000000000000000

Is the map data, loaded from an external file. Each value represents a different tile to display, which is drawn at x*32 y*32 etc. On larger screen, regardless of img sizes (I've scaled some up for hdpi) the map contents are off. I'm doing it backwards.